# Laravel - Relationships, three layers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm fairly new to Laravel, and I'm starting to build Relationships. I've got some of the fairly easier stuff down pretty quickly, but I'm struggling with something a tad more advanced.

Essentially, I have three things:

- Contacts
- Moments
- Goals

Under each Contact I can save an Moments, different things I have done with said Contact.
Each Moment can also be linked to a Goal.

Now, I'm trying to create a page which will display all of my Goals, under which will appear each of my Moments, and for each Moment I want some basic information as to who the Moment is attached to.

Here is how my tables are setup:

Goals table:

```
 - id - Goal name - Goal description
```

Moments table:

```
- id - userId - goalId - Moment name - Description
```

User table

```
- id - firstname - lastname
```

So I've got:

```
class Goal extends Model
{

    public function contact() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Contact');
    }

    public function moments() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Moment', 'goalId');
        }
}
```

And I've tried the following code to get all the results:

```
    $goals = Goal::with('moments', 'contact')
        ->where('authId', Auth::id())
        ->where('hidden', 'false')
        ->get();

    dd($goals);
```

But all contacts return as null... I've tried different things but haven't been able to figure this one out just yet.

Does it use hasManyThrough or something like that?

Edit: So I've been able to put it all together, but not in the order I want.
Using:

```
public function contact() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Contact', 'userId');
}

public function goal() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Goal', 'goalId', 'id');
}


$moments = Moment::with('goal', 'contact')
        ->where('authId', Auth::id())
        ->where('hidden', 'false')
        ->get();

    dd($moments);
```

I now have a $moments object which has links to the correct goal and contact, except I want to be able to sort it by goal, is this feasible?

Thanks for your help !

Cheers,
Mark

---

## Solved

Solved it using the following:

```
public function contacts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Contact', 'id', 'userId');
}

public function moments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Moment', 'goalId');
}

    $goals = Goal::with('moments', 'moments.contact')
        ->where('authId', Auth::id())
        ->where('hidden', 'false')
        ->get();

    dd($goals);
```

Comment: how does, goal and contact related? foreign key? if so i can't find it in **- id - Goal name - Goal description**. Laravel tend to expect contact_id existed in goal table.

Comment: The code for your contact relationship is currently assuming there is a `contact_id` field on the `goals` table. Is this the case?

Comment: no, if it exist, tried to run it without your where clause? i suspect something to do with string related where.

Comment: @Tezla Goal and contact aren't directly related. Goals can contain many Moments, each Moment is assigned to a single Contact.

Comment: @MarkHadjHamou, then it uses [pivot table](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships). notice the `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->withPivot('column1', 'column2');`. basically in you model, you miss `->withPivot`. As for **hasManyThrough**, it works for a-b-c with relation a-b is one to many, and b-c is one to many.

Comment: @Tezla I'm struggling to understand how I would apply Pivot to my example, do you mind explaining?

Comment: @Tezla Is there no way to obtain a structure like $goal->moment->contact->firstname for example? An object with three layers

Comment: no, it is possible. sorry, i should assume **hasManyThrough** is the correct answer for yours regarding *Goals can contain many Moments, each Moment is assigned to a single Contact.* your goal's contact something like `return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Contact', 'App\Moments');` i think. Alternatively, try to retrieve it via `::with('moments.contact')`. Sorry, i got lost myself..

Answer (score 2):

## Solved

Solved it using the following:

```
public function contacts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Contact', 'id', 'userId');
}

public function moments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Moment', 'goalId');
}

    $goals = Goal::with('moments', 'moments.contact')
        ->where('authId', Auth::id())
        ->where('hidden', 'false')
        ->get();

    dd($goals);
```